Ignoring curly braces when citing JSON code
Is there any other way to escape curly braces in JSON code when citing code using the \texttt{} option other than using the backslash?
Using the commandchars=\\\{\} causes the backslash escape character to disappear when rendering the output into PDF using pandoc. However, my developers do not want to escape curly brackets when documenting JSON code. They just want to copy and paste their code into \texttt{}.
Is there some code I can put into a template to have LaTeX ignore open and close curly brackets while still allowing my \texttt{} option to work?
Here is a MWE.
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},fontsize=\small,breaklines=true]

[edit interfaces]
lab@leaf1# \textbf{show ge-0/0/1}
unit 0 \{
    family ethernet-switching \{
        interface-mode trunk;
        vlan \{
            members all;
        \}
    \}
\}

\end{Verbatim}

Using the options following \begin{Verbatim}, LaTeX renders the text bold font of the command, and escapes the curly braces. Removing the [commandchars=\\\{\}] option leaves the curly braces in place, but then my texttt{} command no longer works and the plain text shows up.
Any suggestions?

Do you mean something like the following?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}% for real boldface

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\!\?,fontsize=\small,breaklines=true]
[edit interfaces]
lab@leaf1# \textbf!show ge-0/0/1?
unit 0 {
    family ethernet-switching {
        interface-mode trunk;
        vlan {
            members all;
        }
    }
}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}


If you're using LuaLaTeX you can use unusual Unicode characters.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmonofont{Inconsolatazi4}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[
  commandchars=\⑊\〚\〛,
  fontsize=\small,
  breaklines=true,
]
[edit interfaces]
lab@leaf1# ⑊textbf〚show ge-0/0/1〛
unit 0 {
    family ethernet-switching {
        interface-mode trunk;
        vlan {
            members all;
        }
    }
}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}



Interesting. I had not thought to replace the curly braces around the command with a ! and ?. That would defintely do the trick. Let me test and see if I can use this as an option. Just need to sell it to the devs. Much appreciated.

@KerryCox If you're using LuaLaTeX, you can exploit unusual characters.

I am not familiar with LuaLaTeX. I keep seeing it mentioned. Any sites you can recommend for beginners?

@KerryCox You just add \usepackage{fontspec}.
